Could we change the name on the @StackBrix Twitter account profile?
Currently the full name of our twitter account is:

Brix Stack Exchange

Whilst saving two characters in the account name is possibly valuable understandable when someone else already has the preferred account, there's no need for the "x" to propagate into the full name - please can it be be changed to:

Bricks SE

And then include the site name in the account Bio?

I support this suggestion.

@JoeWreschnig Heh, I did think about waiting, but the Brix thing just makes me sad.

Why not Bricks.SE?

No real reason, other than Stack Exchange is more obvious than SE - I'm really only after the profile name being tweaked, although I saw music.se seems to have changed the account name too. To be honest so long as we lose the x from the profile I'll be happy ;)

FWIW: the account is StackBrix not to save two characters, but because stackbricks was already taken

@shog9 fair enough, as I said this was about the profile full name.

Sorry, this won't work. ):
Twitter enforces a 20 character length limit on the description field.  "LEGO® Answers Stack Exchange" is 28.
The Name field has been changed to "Bricks SE"
The Bio field has been changed to "LEGO® Answers - Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for LEGO® and building block enthusiasts."


Hmm, well either "LEGO® Answers SE" or please just lose the x from the name (which was the original request) so it's "Bricks Stack Exchange"?

Apparently I still couldn't count :S Many thanks Rebecca.


FWIW: the account is StackBrix not to save two characters, but because
  stackbricks was already taken – Shog9

StackBrix sounds cheap and unoriginal.
Could we not use a word divider (delimiter) to divide the words Stack and Bricks? 

Stack-Bricks
Stack.Bricks
Stack:Bricks

It appears Twitter usernames are letters, numbers, and underscores only so the only other option would be:

Stack_Bricks


Actually, since that account is inactive and obscure, it should be possible to contact Twitter to claim that username.
